# How can I establish the communication between my Flutter App and Cardano Blockchain?

Tags: decentralized-applications, blockfrost

Did anybody succeed with building a Flutter App that can communicate with the Cardano Blockchain? I would be happy if I could get some more guidance.

I'm trying to build a cross-platform Dapp, so I do not want to rely on running a full node. So Blockfrost.io comes in handy. Unfortunately there seems to be [no official Dart Package](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#section/SDKs).

I've already tried with [this blockfrost package](https://pub.dev/packages/blockfrost) but somehow I did not manage to put everything together correctly. Did it work for any of you?

I wanted to reach out before I try to build Flutter-Plugins for Android and iOS using the official Java-/Kotlin-/Swift-SDKs provided by Blockfrost.

Comment: It appears that blockfrost is having a few issues atm. A blockfrost dev commented on my question here https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6934/ppviewhashesdontmatch-and-unspendableutxonodatumhash-error-on-redeeming-funds-fr?noredirect=1#comment3186_6934.

Comment: That's not what I'm facing. It's not that I get errors from Blockfrost API. I'm struggling to setup the communication in the first place. I might have to ask that question in a Flutter-specific forum maybe.

Anyway I thought maybe someone can help. If not I will update this post and let others know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out this package, https://pub.dev/packages/blockfrost.  I know this package is being used in at least one place for the Manzano app which can be found here, https://manzano.studio/#/

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use the library. I just struggled with the setup. If others struggle with Flutter/Cardano aswell I'm answering what I've been doing to get things going.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for me, these steps may work for you.

1. Work through [this tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) from flutter.dev
2. Afterwards it should be easy for you to change the code. Instead of `class Album` you want to have `class CurrentBackendTime`. Instead of the function `<Future>Album fetchAlbum()` you want to have `<Future>CurrentBackendTime fetchCurrentBackendTime()` and so on. From the [API-Docs for GET /health/clock](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Health/paths/%7E1health%7E1clock/get) you can learn how to parse data from JSON, which datatypes are required and what data you will get.
3. Since GET /health/clock requires authentication (see API-Docs again) you need to create an HTTP-Header within your `<Future>CurrentBackendTime fetchCurrentBackendTime()` function:

   ```
   final Map<String, String> authHeader = Map<String, String>();
   authHeader['project_id'] = 'PUT YOUR BLOCKFROST API KEY IN HERE!'
   ```

   and then you just add the header to your `http.get()`-Call:

   ```
   final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/health/clock'),
    headers: authHeader,
   );
   ```
4. You could now create more classes like `class AccountRewardHistory`, `class AddressDetails` for all the objects you want to GET from blockfrost's API. Or you just use what you've learnt, and apply it when using a library like blockfrost.